# Module not found error when using nodemailer, nextauth, and useState in NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I'm trying to make a simple web page that shows a form component for a user to post a tweet if they are  authenticated.
Currently, I am using NextAuth with an email provider for authentication- the email provider I'm using is nodemailer.

I haven't been having any issues until I tried to use useState on my home page. In the page, I use `getServerSession(options)` to get the authentication session details, and if there is an authenticated session, I then show a Tweet component.
This Tweet component uses the useState function, so (based on error messages) I put a `"use client"` tag at the top of the component file. However, I think this is what is causing the issues- I can only use nodemailer in server components, so it spits out a series of errors saying "Module not found: Can't resolve ___" where the ___ is a package, like 'fs', or 'net', ... the list keeps going. I have followed other SO posts to get rid of these errors, but each time it spits out a new package. I believe this is because nodemailer can only be used in server components (
https://github.com/nodemailer/nodemailer/issues/1564, related post).

Based on the github forum, I see that the issue is with trying to use nodemailer on the client side, but as a beginner, I do not understand why it is even being called on the client side. I was able to use `getServerSession` to test authentication earlier and successfully print out either "logged in" or "logged out", so I'm not sure why using the NewTweet component is creating an issue. I have applied a "use server" tag in the route.js file in my next auth folder to try to fix it.

Here are the files:

route.js (to handle NextAuth)

```
"use server";
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import options from './options'

const handler = NextAuth(options)

export {handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

page.js

```
"use client";
import Link from 'next/link.js'
import options from './/api/auth/[...nextauth]/options.js'
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'
import NewTweet from 'components/NewTweet.js'

export default async function Home(){
  const session = await getServerSession(options)
  console.log(session)
  return(
    <div>
      <Link href='/api/auth/signin'>Log In!</Link>
      <div>
        {session ? <NewTweet /> : <p>You are not logged in!</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
    
  )
}
```

NewTweet.js

```
"use client";
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'
import { useState } from 'react'
import options from '../src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/options.js'
export default function NewTweet(){
    const [content, setContent] = useState('')

    return(
        <div>
            <form
            onSubmit={async (e) => {
                e.preventDefault()

                if (!content) {
                    alert('No content')
                    return
                }

                alert(content)
            }}
            >
            <div className='flex'>
                <div className='flex-1 px-1 pt-2 mt-2 mr-1 ml-1'>
                    <textarea
                        className='border p-4 w-full text-lg font-medium bg-transparent outline-none color-primary '
                        rows={2}
                        cols={50}
                        placeholder="What's happening?"
                        name='content'
                        onChange={(e) => setContent(e.target.value)}
                    />
                </div>
            </div>
            <div className='flex'>
                <div className='flex-1 mb-5'>
                    <button className = 'border float-right px-8 py-2 mt-0 mr-2 font-bold rounded-full'>
                        Send Tweet!
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </form>
        </div>
    )

}
```

Here is the error:

```
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/dkim/index.js:10:0
Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs'

https://nextjs.org/docs/messages/module-not-found

Import trace for requested module:
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/mailer/index.js
./node_modules/nodemailer/lib/nodemailer.js
./node_modules/next-auth/providers/email.js
./src/app/api/auth/[...nextauth]/options.js
./components/NewTweet.js
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay this is quite an easy one, I advice you read the next-auth docs. [Here](https://next-auth.js.org)

**NewTweet.js** and **page.js** are both client components and you're not allowed to import `import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'` within client components, this will only be possible within server components.

For client components you use `import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";`

for route.js the rework should be:

```
import NextAuth from 'next-auth'
import options from './options'

const handler = NextAuth(options)

export {handler as GET, handler as POST}
```

for page.js the rework should be:

```
import Link from 'next/link'
import options from '../api/auth/[...nextauth]/options.js'
import { getServerSession } from 'next-auth'
import NewTweet from 'components/NewTweet.js'

export default async function Home(){
  const session = await getServerSession(options)
  console.log(session)
  return(
    <div>
      <Link href='/api/auth/signin'>Log In!</Link>
      <div>
        {session ? <NewTweet /> : <p>You are not logged in!</p>}
      </div>
    </div>
    
  )
}
```

for NewTweet.js the rework should be

```
import { useState } from 'react'
import { useSession } from "next-auth/react";
export default function NewTweet(){
    const [content, setContent] = useState('')

    const {data: session} = useSession()
    console.log("Current USer Session", session)

    return(
        <div>
        ...
        </div>
    )

})
}
```